# Safeguard code from changes made by other programmers

Tags: c#, structure, collaboration

In C# I have a class that is using a function to do some work. The thing is: this function needs the class to a have a specific structure in order for it to return correct results (for "specific structure" you can imagine the class using a specific set of enumeratives that the function relies on as well).

My question is: what is the best way to try and safeproof my function from future changes to the structure of the using class? Or at least have it so that if another programmer changes the class' structure my function will notify him that changes to the function itself are needed in order for everything to work correctly.

I hope everything is clear. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write unit tests and make sure that everybody runs them on each code change (or commit, at least). If a breaking change is made, the tests will fail and the developer will realise that something is wrong. If the tests are descriptive enough they will show the developer what they need to fix.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for unit tests as @joews suggested

If you cannot / don't want to use them, a very rough way to deal with this:
In the first line of Main, call a method `CheckMyClass()`

```
void CheckMyClass()
{
#if DEBUG
    bool theClassIsOK = ...//check your class is still how it should be.
    if (! theClassIsOK)
        throw new ApplicationException ("something changed TheClass in a wrong way, DiG knows what's wrong with this");
#endif
}
```

Not elegant at all, I know.

Replace "DiG knows" with something more useful for your collegues (or ex collegues, since they will modify the class the day after you found a new job...)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make sure your function gets the dependencies it needs is to pass them in explicitly as arguments. So don't require an instance of the class as an argument, but rather each of the enumerations or other class members.

You could also consider making the class implement an interface with all the required attributes. If you distribute the interface along with your function in an assembly, people won't be able to change it.

Finally, you could put assertions into your function and return exceptions if the assertions aren't true.